# Reversing a linked list using 2 pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wrote a code to reverse a linked list using two pointers. At a time, I am reversing 1 pointer between 2 nodes. The code looks fine to me.

```
Node* reverse(Node *head)
{
    Node *p = head;
    Node *q = p->next;
    Node *temp;
    while (q != NULL)   {
        temp = p;
        p = q->next;
        q->next = temp;

        temp = p;
        p=q;
        q=temp;
    }
    head = p;
    return p;
}
```

What is the logical fault here?

Comment: Please take some time to review [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are swapping the elements side by side, which will effectively just move the head to the end of the list. You need to be swapping the start and the end element then moving towards the middle of the linked list.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I am swapping the links between the elements side by side, and then making the head point to last element. So effectively the linked list is reversed.
10->20->30->40->50 to 10<-20<-30<-40<-50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I missed was that I didn't make the next of first node of the original linked list point to ***NULL***. That's why it was going into infinite loop.

```
Node* reverse(Node *head)
{
    Node *p = head;
    Node *q = p->next;
    Node *temp;
    p->next=NULL;
    while (q != NULL)   {
        temp = p;            
        p = q->next;
        q->next = temp;

        temp = p;
        p=q;
        q=temp;
    }
    head = p;
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Node* reverse(Node *head)
{
    if(!head)
        return nullptr;
    Node *p = head;
    Node *q = p->next;
    p->next = nullptr;
    while(q != NULL)
    {
        Node *temp = q->next;
        q->next = p;
        p = q;
        q = temp;
    }
    head = p;
    return p;
}
```